# illegal group name installing mongodb on mac

Tags: linux, macos, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
sudo chmod 0755 /data/db
sudo chown mongod:mongod /data/db
```

I got `chown: mongod: illegal group name` after the 3rd line of command, the first 2 is working fine. No idea what's wrong, I was following tutorial on a book.

Comment: What is the output of `id mongod`? ...

Comment: id: mongod: no such user

Comment: So obviously you need to create a user `mongod` that belongs to the group `mongod` ... If you want your user to use the db then change it to `youruser:yourgroup`

Comment: what is that group thingy for? is that compulsory?

Comment: On Unix/Linux file systems each user belongs to a group that defines what the users in that group can do. To check which group you belong to do `id yourusername`, the primary group  `gid` is usually the first to the right of the `uid`.

Comment: so what should I do? `uid=501(james) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)`

Comment: Change line 3 to `sudo chown james:staff /data/db`

Comment: what is that `20` value for? means me (james) is under group of `staff`?

Comment: Exactly. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130685/understanding-the-staff-user-group

Comment: I want to learn more about this command thingy for future group, what is this thing call? linux?

Comment: In terminal you can get info about any command: "man (command)", in this case "man chown".

Comment: I can launch mongodb by typing `mongodb`. but what to do next? I want to show my db, so I type mongo but it doesn't give me back anything.

Comment: I got `No manual entry for mongodb`

Comment: Then I would recommend https://docs.mongodb.com

Comment: can u advise how to pickup things that u want to learn? usually i don't read the whole documentation, is that the correct way of learning programming?